# Displaying PDF content in new tab using ui:outputURL not working by clicking, But working by "Open link in new tab"

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I have been trying to display PDF content in a new tab using `ui:outputURL`. It's not working by clicking, but working by "Open link in new tab".

Component:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" controller="CCGComponentControllerPC">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.testPdfHandler}" />

<ui:outputURL aura:id="oURL" value="" label="Test Pdf" target="_blank" />
```

Controller :

```
testPdfHandler : function(component, event, helper) {
    var data = response;
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/pdf"}),
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var oURL = component.find("oURL");
    oURL.set("v.value", url);
    oURL.set("v.label", url);
}
```

Is there any workaround for this issue?

Comment: did you find any solution? Thanks!

Comment: Yes can you update if this is solved ?